# Determining if certain courses are taken together frequently in a term. R analysis

Tags: r, data-analysis

Assuming a table that gives student ID and the courses they took (like English 101, Math 101, etc) and the term term the course was taken in (Fall 2022, Spring 2023, etc) what is the best way to go about finding if students tended to take certain courses together in the same semester?

What's the general term for this analysis?

Possibly similar to [R: Which products are bought together more frequently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279249/r-which-products-are-bought-together-more-frequently) but that doesn't give the general term for this analysis type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of analysis is called "Association Rule Mining", some packages that you can check out in R are "arules" and "arulesViz" which can be used to perform association rule mining on this type of data.

This medium article is pretty helpful in explaining this concept.

Hope this helps! :)